# What do I do after the Hide-and-Seek game in Clock Town?

Tags: zelda-majoras-mask

I found the fairy and I did the hide and seek game, but now I'm kinda lost. I skipped the dialog by accident and now I don't know what to do.

Comment: You need to be much more specific.

Comment: go into the bombers hideout and go to the observatory to get the moons tear

Answer (score 2):

The Bombers should have given you a 5-digit code after you found them all. If you don't remember the code and don't have the Bombers' Notebook, you can complete their Hide-and-Seek game again to get the code again.

Talk to the Bomber in East Clock Town and tell him the code, that will give you access to the sewers. Follow the sewers to the observatory, and you should continue the story there.

Comment: Yes, this is one of those awkward parts of the game where you have to write something down. The Bomber's Notebook will show the code on the submenu -- but you can't get the Bomber's Notebook until sometime in the second cycle -- which means you'll need to write it down somewhere else to use in the meantime.